# When using position:absolute, how do I define that I want the bottom edge of one element aligned against the top edge of another?

Tags: html, css

I have a column of text, with wide margins on either side.  Below it, I have a full-width section of data (in tabular format).

I can align these against each other quite readily.  My problem is that there is a 'tab' that sits on top of the table section.  It's narrow enough that it doesn't interfere with the center column of text, and the layout calls for it to slide up into the white space to the left of the text.

The easy solution would a position:absolute, with top:foopx to slide it up relative to the rest of the div.  The only problem is, the tab's height is dynamic.  I need to somehow to top:'height'px, but (obviously) CSS doesn't contain anything for dynamic values.

What I need to do is align the bottom edge of the 'tab' against the *top* edge of the containing div, and I cannot for the life of me figure out any CSS statement that does that.  I'd rather avoid a javascript based approach (e. g. at runtime get the height of the tab, then set top equal to that height) because the entire bottom div is refreshed from time to time using an AJAX call, and adjusting the height in that process causes the page to 'jitter' on the update (not sure why it doesn't happen without the height update; the jitter is in a separate section of the code).

Requested code example:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#smallColumn
{
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:#000;
    margin:5px;
}
#fullColumn
{
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    height:300px;
    background:#000;
    margin:5px;
}   
#bottomDiv
{
    position:relative;
}
#tab
{
    position:absolute;
    top:-40px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="smallColumn">a</div>
<div id="fullColumn">b</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<div id="bottomDiv">
    <div id="tab">Tab</div>
<hr />
DATA DATA DATA
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post some code and/or screenshot?

Comment: Is it the tab height that is dynamic?

Comment: Yes, the tab height is dynamic.

Comment: How about a URL? Perhaps others have working crystal balls, but Without a URL, any answer from me is pure conjecture.

Comment: @PeteWilson Does the code example I gave help?

Comment: Thanks for posting code, updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use top margins, the appropriate `display` properties and `vertical-align:bottom`. See the code below + comments for an explanation. You have to set a `height` and  negative `margin-top` value which is larger than the actual height of the tab's content. Otherwise, the content may jump back to the top.

Relevant HTML/CSS:

```
<div id="cont">
    <div id="tab">
        <div id="tab-fix">
            Tab
        </div>
    </div>
    Rest of content
</div>

#cont {
    margin-top: 30px; /*Reserve space*/
    height: 100px;
    background: lightgreen;
}
#tab {
    display: table; /* Necessary for the application */
    margin-top: -30px;/* Move tab to the top*/
}
#tab-fix {
    height: 30px; /* Expecting the height to not exceed 30px*/
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom; /* Aligns the content at the bottom*/
}
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/stEW3/2/**

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, the height of the tab is dynamic.  Otherwise, this would be trivial.

Comment: @RonLugge Updated answer + Fiddle. The height doesn't matter any more.

Comment: Note: The extra DIV is necessary, for the following reason: The `vertical-align` CSS property is only effective on *inline* elements, which cannot be resized using `height:` and `width:`. The `display:table` + `display:table-cell;vertical-align:bottom;` combination, however, produces the desired result: The content is aligned at the bottom.

Comment: I had to experiment a bit to make it fit other aspects of the page that I hadn't considered relevant to the issue at hand (notably, a right-floated div that contained pagination controls that hadn't caused any issues as long as the tab was left-floated), but this answer solved the asked question.  There are a few issues with clipping when I update (not sure why), but it's much better than it was to begin with.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Update2**

So this is a tough problem to solve! The only thing I could think of was to put a wrapper around the tab. That wrapper needs to be relatively positioned and have a height equal to that of the tab. Then you can use absolute and negative top of 100%.

http://jsfiddle.net/mrtsherman/BC8Xr/2/

**Update**

With posted code I now understand. How about using absolute and specifying a bottom value of 0?

http://jsfiddle.net/mrtsherman/BC8Xr/

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="smallColumn">a</div>
    <div id="fullColumn">b</div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <div id="bottomDiv">
        <div id="tab">Something</div>
        <hr />
    </div>
</div>

#content { border: 1px solid red; position: relative; } 
#bottomDiv
{
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
#tab
{
    /*
    position:absolute;
    top:-40px;
    */
}
```

**Old**

Without html structure and a somewhat vague description this is a bit hard to decipher. But this is what I think you mean:

http://jsfiddle.net/mrtsherman/VM99L/

Basically you want the tab above the tabular data to be drawn up into the div before it. You can use a negative top margin for this. Just set it to the same height as the height of your tab. If you have padding on the div then you will need to compensate for that also.

```
<div id="tabulardata">
    <div id="tab">Tab X</div>
    <table>
        <tr><td>data</td></tr>
        <tr><td>data</td></tr>
        <tr><td>data</td></tr>
        <tr><td>data</td></tr>
        <tr><td>data</td></tr>        
    </table>
</div>

#tabulardata { margin-top: -50px; }
#tab { height: 50px; width: 80px; background: gray; color: white;  }
```

Comment: I've added a code example that you can copy and paste into any HTML file to see what I'm aiming at.  You actually came very close to exactly what my issue is, you just missed that the tab height is supposed to be dynamic.

Comment: The problem with bottom:0 is that it aligns the bottom edge of the tab, with the bottom edge of the containing div.  I could use bottom:-height of the div, but again that requires dynamic content.

Comment: @RonLugge - I guess I don't understand then. You want the bottom of element X aligned with the top of element Y? What are X and Y in your html?

Comment: I want the bottom edge of the tab, aligned with the top edge of the containing div (the data)

Comment: @RonLugge - I see. I made one more stab at it. Probably not the best solution for you, but best I could come up with. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your efforts -- you're right, this was a tough problem to solve!  Thanks very much for the attempt.  If I had a public-facing page I could use to display this, it probably would have made a lot more sense, but my client doesn't want me pasting links everywhere just yet.